# Cannot get postfix to listen on wifi interface (en1)

Tags: mac, network, smtp

I have a Mac running 10.8.4 which I am using as a server which is only connected to my network via Wifi (`en1`), however I cannot get the stock `postfix` process to listen on `en1`.  I have tried a variety of `inet_interfaces` settings, for example the default setting of `all`, gives:

```
# netstat -an | fgrep .25
tcp6       0      0  ::1.25                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.25           *.*                    LISTEN
```

I have also tried:

```
inet_interfaces = 192.168.1.100, 127.0.0.1
inet_interfaces = 192.168.1.0, 127.0.0.1
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
```

But I can see no listen on `en1`.  Can anyone advise?  Should I ditch the stock `postfix` and use the Macports one?

(note that I have unloaded and loaded `postfix` using `launchctl` between config changes).

Comment: The standard setup of postfix listens on all networks you should not need to set this, How have you setup the postfix daemon in LaunchAgents etc?

Comment: @Mark Yeah I have used the `launchd` `.plist` provided with the system.  The default `inet_interfaces` setting should work out-of-the-box, however it doesn't.  Perhaps there is something else going on that I'm not aware of with the Mac version?

Answer (score 1):

OK, long-story-short, there was an additional `inet_interfaces` line right at the bottom of the file, which has the setting `loopback_only`.  I can only assume it was written there by some automated tool incapable of properly parsing and recreating the config file.